Installing usepackages on miktex
Good day.
I am a new user of Miktex. I have issue installing missed packages. I have tried several options to no avail. Anytime I try to install or used a missed package, a page will pop up saying proxy authentication required, asking me to supply authentication Name and Password. Please, how can I address this problem?
Thank you.

Did you, in the Miktex update setup, try to add packages as the admin or user ? This makes a difference. In my view it is better to choose the admin to add, or update, packages.

if you are behind a proxy you will have to find out the password, if not uncheck in the miktex console the proxy requirement (settings->general, click on "change" and then connection settings.)
